# c3p0 in hibernate does not close idle connections

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm in little trouble with a fact c3p0 doesn't close idle connections despite the fact hibernate.cfg.xml file has a sufficient content. Here's a part of the file mentioned above:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://***.***.***.***/dev</property>
        <property name="connection.username">*******</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*******</property>
        <!--<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>-->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>

    <!-- pooling -->

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">180</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

In example, when I use the "search" button in the application frontend, the request is sent and on the database dashboard I can see one idle COMMIT transaction. After the time given in hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period and hibernate.c3p0.timeout I assume this transaction should dissapear, but unfortunately it does not ...

Comment: Your min size is set to 1. So a single connection may be open. Did you try with two parallel connections and see this reduced to one after the time?

Comment: @Konrad, yes I tried. At this moment many parallel connections exists and they are not being reduced ...